# Showing path integral formalism is Lorentz-invariant without resorting to Hamiltonian formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, covariance

I think people typically say that path integral formalism is manifestly Lorentz-invariant, because Lagrangian density is Lorentz-invariant. However, path formalism is typically defined with time slicing with limit taken to time slicing becoming zero, and time slicing cannot be ignored.

Different coordinates can be defined by Lorentz transformation - the question is, how do I show that time slicing mechanism keeps Lorentz-invariance of the final result without resorting to Hamiltonian formalism then proving it?